# is it ok to use succinct arrow function syntax if I'm not returning a value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, code-readability

Let's say I have the function `pageScroller` **that doesn't return any value**.
Given that the succinct ES6 arrow function syntax implicitly returns the value, is it correct still ok to use it without block around?

```
const goToPage = pageNumber => pageScroller(pageNumber)
```

or I should always prefer the explicit block instead? I.e.:

```
const goToPage = pageNumber => {
  pageScroller(pageNumber)
}
```

My only worrying is that people reading the code can expect that `pageScroller` returns a value. What do you think?

Comment: Why not `const goToPage = pageScroller;` ? But actually thats quite opinion based.

Comment: Technically every JavaScript function returns a value. In most cases it's `undefined`.

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely opinion based but you're not wrong to want to be cautious about other people thinking you might be trying to assign a value.

I'd recommend looking at the code again after a couple weeks of working with something else and see if you recognize what it's doing immediately. Also, think about if the goToPage const will ever need to do anything other than call the pageScroller. If there's any chance it would, you might be better off calling the explicit block. If there isn't, maybe see if you can just call pageScroller directly instead of using a const?